# How to set a custom value on a property of the Model in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, properties, model, data-annotations

When I create a Model in MVC3, is there any workaround to set a custom value on a property like in the following example [MyCustomValue()] and how to get later that value programmatically?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class MyModel

    Public Property MyModelId As Integer

    <StringLength(20), MyCustomValue(True)>
    Public Property Name As String

[...]
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AntP I found an example on how to set a custom attribute on a class (therefore also a Model) and how to get it programmatically

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw5zxet9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx